# Get video id from facebook with regex

Tags: php, regex

http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=107084586333124

and

http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?more=diffictult&v=107084586333124

I need a regex that would get the **v** number out of both urls. It must also match that it's a facebook url.
Please do not give **parse_str** and **parse_url** solutions. I actually need the regex.

Thanks.

Comment: You should consider trying to write the regex yourself (take a 10 minute tutorial) before asking for SO to write your code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hardcode, try this

```
if (preg_match('~\bfacebook\.com.*?\bv=(\d+)~', $url, $id)) {
    $values = $id[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try with following regex:

```
[?&]v=(\d+)
```

Comment: This does not match that it is also a facebook (or any website) url. This condition made it impossible for me to find a solution on the internet. Can you add a control for that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex and you shouldn't use it.

It's slower and more difficult to implement, properly.

```
$url = 'http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=107084586333124';

if (stripos('//www.facebook.com', $url) !== false) {
    $query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
    parse_str($query, $params);
    $video = $params['v'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but this solution is plentful on the internet. Thats why I wrote specifically that I need a regex.

Comment: That's not a reason not to use it. Why do you explicitly need regex? I don't see any reason not to use the functions PHP provided especially for your use case.

Comment: I am developing my own emfield extension module for Drupal 6. And the parent module uses regex on url to figure out which one of the submodule must it use. I should probably explain that in the main post that I have an actual reason for the regex, not just a lack of knowledge.

Comment: @hardcode ok that sounds legit. Well, you have several answers to chose from now :-)

Answer (score 0):

I propose the regex

```
 ^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?facebook\..*v=(\d+)$
```

Here's a demo:

http://regex101.com/r/uR6fV1/3

The number you desire will be in the first capturing group.

Comment: I get an "No ending delimiter '^' found" error. Can you give a code example with preg_match ? Thanks.